# Running React Native on different IOS versions

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I have started my ran my React Native project on a Simulator iPhone 13 with iOS 15, although I have changed to an iPhone XR and iOS 12 so It uses last ram (I only have 8gb) but when I attempt to run the project using the `--simulator` flag, it won't make a difference and it will launch in iPhone 13[image].

[image]

Comment: try to use udid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
instruments -s devices
```

Use device's name in the list.

If the device you want to use doesn't exist, install it by using xcode

Comment: It wont work for some reason, it keeps asking to install command line tool, I install it and it asks to install again